# Coding in C, Why are my array values changing?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm using GDB to go through my code and each time the while loop is entered, the values in NameList[] change. Like I set NameList[0] to chr2, but when I go back through the while loop in gdb, I say
x/s NameList[0]
and now it's set to the new value of chr2!
How is this able to happen?
I know I'm changing the pointer, but shouldn't the array be storing the old value of the pointer and not be allowed to update?

```
while (fgets(thisline, length, input) != NULL) {
    chr = strtok(Line, "    ");
    if(chr != NULL) {
        chr2 = strtok(chr, " ")
        int j = 0;
        while(NameList[j] != NULL) {
            j++;
        }
        NameList[j] = chr2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
    NameList[j] = chr2;
```

to

```
    NameList[j] = strdup(chr2);
```

And see what happens. The issue is that you are just storing a pointer to
the char array, and that char array is changing out from under you. The strdup
function copies the whole array.

Comment: @user3002440 But don't forget to `free()` it after use.